# Convert XML to nested JSON object in specific format

Tags: python, json, xml, recursion

This is a follow up to the question I previously asked about deriving a totally flat structure out of an XML node: [Converting an xml doc into a specific dot-expanded json structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983293/converting-an-xml-doc-into-a-specific-dot-expanded-json-structure).

Suppose I have the same XML to start with:

```
<Item ID="288917">
  <Main>
    <Platform>iTunes</Platform>
    <PlatformID>353736518</PlatformID>
  </Main>
  <Genres>
    <Genre FacebookID="6003161475030">Comedy</Genre>
    <Genre FacebookID="6003172932634">TV-Show</Genre>
  </Genres>
  <Products>
    <Product Country="CA">
      <URL>https://itunes.apple.com/ca/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518</URL>
      <Offers>
        <Offer Type="HDBUY">
          <Price>3.49</Price>
          <Currency>CAD</Currency>
        </Offer>
        <Offer Type="SDBUY">
          <Price>2.49</Price>
          <Currency>CAD</Currency>
        </Offer>
      </Offers>
    </Product>
    <Product Country="FR">
      <URL>https://itunes.apple.com/fr/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518</URL>
      <Rating>Tout public</Rating>
      <Offers>
        <Offer Type="HDBUY">
          <Price>2.49</Price>
          <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        </Offer>
        <Offer Type="SDBUY">
          <Price>1.99</Price>
          <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        </Offer>
      </Offers>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Item>
```

Now I would like to convert it into a nested json object in a specific format (slightly different than the `xmltodict`  library. Here is the structure I'd like to derive:

```
{
    "Item[@ID]": 288917,
    "Item.Main.Platform": "iTunes",
    "Item.Main.PlatformID": "353736518",
    "Item.Genres": [
        {
            "[@FacebookID]": "6003161475030",
            "Value": "Comedy"
        },
        {
            "[@FacebookID]": "6003161475030",
            "Value": "TV-Show"
        }
    ],
    "Item.Products": [
        {
            "[@Country]": "CA",
            "URL": "https://itunes.apple.com/ca/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",
            "Offers.Offer": [
                {
                    "[@Type]": "HDBUY",
                    "Price": "3.49",
                    "Currency": "CAD"
                }
                {
                    "[@Type]": "SDBUY",
                    "Price": "2.49",
                    "Currency": "CAD"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "[@Country]": "FR",
            "URL": "https://itunes.apple.com/fr/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",
            "Offers.Offer": [
                {
                    "[@Type]": "HDBUY",
                    "Price": "3.49",
                    "Currency": "EUR"
                }
                {
                    "[@Type]": "SDBUY",
                    "Price": "1.99",
                    "Currency": "EUR"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The main difference being instead of collapsing everything into a list of flat values, to allow lists of dicts. How could this be done?

Comment: You can do this using XSLT, even version 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

While doing the above might be a nice challenge, [`xmltodic`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/blob/master/xmltodict.py) already does a great job with this and can do the job with slight altering.

And here are the changes to make in `xmltodict`:

1. Change var [cdata_key](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/blob/master/xmltodict.py#L44) from `#text` to `Value`.
2. Change var [attr_prefix](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/blob/master/xmltodict.py#L43) from `@` to `[@`.
3. Add new var `attr_suffix=']'` to init method.
4. Change [attr_key](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/blob/master/xmltodict.py#L105) to `key = self.attr_prefix+self._build_name(key)+self.attr_suffix`.

That should give the exact result you're looking for with a tested module:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> import xmltodict
>>> import json
>>> from utils import xmltodict
>>> node= etree.fromstring(s)
>>> d=xmltodict.parse(etree.tostring(node))
>>> print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
{
    "Item": {
        "[@ID]": "288917",
        "Main": {
            "Platform": "iTunes",
            "PlatformID": "353736518"
        },
        "Genres": {
            "Genre": [
                {
                    "[@FacebookID]": "6003161475030",
                    "Value": "Comedy"
                },
                {
                    "[@FacebookID]": "6003172932634",
                    "Value": "TV-Show"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Products": {
            "Product": [
                {
                    "[@Country]": "CA",
                    "URL": "https://itunes.apple.com/ca/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",
                    "Offers": {
                        "Offer": [
                            {
                                "[@Type]": "HDBUY",
                                "Price": "3.49",
                                "Currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            {
                                "[@Type]": "SDBUY",
                                "Price": "2.49",
                                "Currency": "CAD"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "[@Country]": "FR",
                    "URL": "https://itunes.apple.com/fr/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",
                    "Rating": "Tout public",
                    "Offers": {
                        "Offer": [
                            {
                                "[@Type]": "HDBUY",
                                "Price": "2.49",
                                "Currency": "EUR"
                            },
                            {
                                "[@Type]": "SDBUY",
                                "Price": "1.99",
                                "Currency": "EUR"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to do this.